# xlwings / COM API format table

Tags: pandas, xlwings

I'm currently using xlwings in Python/Excel and would like to format a table after putting a value with a pandas DataFrame. However, I can't format the table as I want. Indeed, it seems the API doesn't understand that the columns are already set.
Could you please tell me how to do so? Here is my code:

```
range_ = wb.sheets[sheet_name].range("B2")
range_.expand().clear_contents()
range_.options(pd.DataFrame, index=True).value = data_df

range_.select()

tbl = wb.sheets[sheet_name].api.ListObjects.add()           
tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium4"
tbl.DisplayName = table_name
```

However, in the XL file, the first row (headers) is set as: Column 1, Column 2 and so on, instead of using the columns of my ```data_df````.
Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have moved on by now, but in case anyone else is searching for this, I was able to achieve this by using

```
ws = xw.Book.caller().sheets[sheet_name]
ws.range('A1').options(index=False, header=True).value = df
rng = ws.range('A1').expand('table')
tbl = ws.api.ListObjects.add(1,ws.api.Range(rng.address),False,1)
```

The 4th input parameter on the ListObjects.Add call controls the header. You can find more information about the ListObject parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add)